# Effective installer for large applications

Tags: c#, installation

I have a big application, which includes multiple modules (desktop,web)
Applications written using C#
application has abo many desktop tools
we use visual studio installer for years to prepare msi files
but now we need to develop one group installer that takes care of installing application and tools and
also uninstall them
something like visual studio setup, customer can choose tools and install them and not installing each part separately

need to know please recommended installers for this task

We tried WIX and visual studio installers but we noticed that wix is declining in market, needs help if this is true and is the recommended alternatives

Comment: **`advanced installer`**  is a good tools for making setups

Comment: Have You try `Inno Setup` ?

Comment: Actually we are seeking free tool but I don't know whether WIX is declining or still used and supported from microsoft